# EF Core - "map" local objects to database objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, object

maybe I just don't know the right keywords but I really cannot find the solution for my problem.

I am deserializing an XML invoice to object `RawInvoice`. Then I create object `Invoice` and copy properties from `RawInvoice` to `Invoice` (because of different structure).

Now I need to "map" or "link" some `Article` items to already existing items in database. There is also a problem that the deserialized `Article` object does not have all properties as in database, it has only the `Name` property.

My only idea now is for loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < rawInvoice.Items.InvoiceItemContents.Count; i++)
{
    invoice.InvoiceItems[i].Article = _invoiceContext.Articles.Where(a => a.Name == invoice.InvoiceItems[i].Article.Name).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

but I believe there must be another and better way, maybe built-in command for something like this. I'd like to have (hopefully) single query which will do this for me.

My second idea was MySQL trigger on before insert, but I would still rather have this handled in code.

So - is there any way to do it simply? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, add `ArticleId` to the Article DTO and set `InvoiceItem.ArticleId`, not `InvoiceItem.Article`.

Comment: Problem is I know only name and two other properties from that XML. I have to look for existing article by these 3 props